# Cайт выполнил переадресацию слишком много раз Customize.php

Tags: wordpress

При попытке настроить сайт,(Customize.php) Пишет

> Сайт выполнил переадресацию слишком много раз.

Вчера сам сайт выдавал такую ошибку, разобрался вроде через htaccess

[image]

Теперь не грузит сайт вообще